# File System on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, directory

How are files stored in Ubuntu 12.04? In Windows, if you look at your local disk (C:), you will see that programs installed are traditionally kept in Program Files and Program Files (x86) if you have a 64 bit system. Further more, each user's folders such as documents, downloads, pictures, etc. can be accessed through C:\Users\

Where are the different users' folders (Documents, Downloads, etc.) located in for Ubuntu 12.04. Suppose I have setup multiple users on Ubuntu. How can I access another user's folders? And lastly, where are the 'installed files' kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All folder in Ubuntu are in **/**, called *the root directory*.
Every user has a folder (named as his username) in **/home**. You can reach your home with command **cd ~** in a terminal, and other home directory with `cd /home/username`.

There is no installed directory, all programs are in a lots of directory, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview#Main_directories for further information.